# Mail not being received after adding a ReplyRecipient

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

Using Outlook for Microsoft Office 365 32 bit and Delphi XE8

I am evaluation Redemption.dll as Windows 11 has blocked my application from accessing Outlook.

I have Outlook configure with multiple profiles and stores

I can open the profiles find the store/account and can send/receive.

In one combination I do not receive the email.

The issue is with

```
Mail.ReplyRecipients.Add('xxx@gmail.com');
```

if I comment this line out I receive the email

In the sent folder I can dblclick and by clicking reply I see the Reply Address but in the inbox (of the recipient) I get nothing.  I scanned all Outlook items to no avail.

In the reverse direction I do receive the email.

I intend ti purchase the product on completion of my evaluation. But this feature is important

```
procedure TForm61._Send(Profile, Sender, _To, _CC, _BCC, Subject, Body: String;
  ReadReceiptRequested: Boolean; _Attachments: TArray<String>);
var
  FolderFound: Boolean;
  c, j, Count, k: Integer;

  Session: IRDOSession;
  Store: IRDOStore;
  Drafts: IRDOFolder;
  Recip: IRDORecipient;
  MAil: IRDOMail;
  IPMRoot: IRDOFolder;
  ReplyRecip: IRDORecipient;
  _name: String;
begin
  Session:=CoRDOSession.Create;
  Session.Logon(Profile,'', False, True,EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
  Drafts:=Session.GetFolderFromPath('\\'+Sender+'\Inbox');

  Mail:= Drafts.Items.Add(olMailItem);
  Recip := Mail.Recipients.Add(_To);
  Recip.type_:= olTo;
  if not _CC.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Recip := Mail.Recipients.Add(_CC);
    Recip.type_:= olCC;
  end;
  if not _BCC.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Recip := Mail.Recipients.Add(_BCC);
    Recip.type_:= olBCC;
  end;
//    Recip.Resolve(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);

//   ReplyRecip:=Mail.ReplyRecipients.Add('xxx@gmail.com');
     Mail.ReplyRecipients.Add('xxx@gmail.com');

//   ReplyRecip.Resolve(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);

  for j:=0 to Length(_Attachments)- 1 do
    Mail.Attachments.Add(_Attachments[j], EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);

  Mail.Subject:=Subject;
  Mail.ReadReceiptRequested:=ReadReceiptRequested;
  Mail.HTMLBody:=Body;

  if SignatureIndex>-1 then
  begin
    Signature:=Session.Signatures.Item(SignatureIndex+1);  //noy zero-based
    Signature.ApplyTo(Mail, False);
  end;
  Mail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested:=True;
  Mail.Save;
  Mail.Send;
end;
```

TIA

Ephraim

Comment: Do you get the same results with OOM? Why do you need to use Redemption for that?

Comment: Doe it matter where it is being sent to? Are you sure it does not end up in the spam folder?